# Check whether product available in main website

Tags: product, stores

When product is not enabled in main website from the backend is there way to find it programmatically?

[image]

I have tried this way. But it shows product id(not false)

```
$product       = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
$productIdMage = $product->getId();

if($productIdMage != false) {
    echo $productIdMage;
}
else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option enables website ids field with product. To check that field, your call should go like this :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
var_dump($product->getWebsiteIds());
```

This will give an array of websites, product is assigned to.

Comment: How to find how many products enabled with website filter using DB or script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will show all the products available in store.

```
  echo '<pre>';
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getId();
    print_r($product->getData());
}
```